# Christmas gift from friends

Tags: riddle

> Can't be found east of the Mississippi River.
>   It moves but has no legs, wings or wheels.
>   It'll hurt you if you touch it.
>   I've seen this all my life but didn't think I'd ever have one.

What is it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you get

> a Western Rattlesnake?

Can't be found east of the Mississippi River.

> As the name implies, found in the Western US/Canada/Mexico

It moves but has no legs, wings or wheels.

> A snake meets these requirements

It'll hurt you if you touch it.

> or more specifically, if you touch it.  But many people have stepped accidentally on one and it hurts.

I've seen this all my life but didn't think I'd ever have one.

> Yes, not exactly a good pet

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> The Mississippi river?

Can't be found east of Mississippi river

> Obviously

It moves but it has no legs, wings or  wheels

> Rivers are in constant movement

It'll hurt you if you touch it

> Not sure about this one, but maybe having something to do with currents and drowning?

I've seen this all my life but didn't think I'd ever have one

> You've seen the river all your life but can't own it

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> a Jellyfish ?

*Can't be found east of the Mississippi River*

> guess there's no jellyfish in Mississippi river

*It moves but has no legs, wings or wheels*

> it moves with its tantacles

*It'll hurt you if you touch it*

> its venom is painful

*I've seen this all my life but didn't think I'd ever have one.*

> who wants to have a jellyfish as a pet?

that's a weird present though